# How to create and restore records using Ember Data

Tags: ember.js

I am new to ember-js i am not able to create and restore data in ember-js using this code please help me.I am not getting any output in the browser.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts">
  <h2>Books Name and Author: </h2>
  {{#each post in controller}}
    <p><b>{{post.book}}</b></p>
    <p><i>{{post.author}}</i></p>
  {{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  App = Ember.Application.create();

  //The store cache of all records available in an application
  App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    //adapter translating requested records into the appropriate calls
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
  });

  App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();      

  App.Router.map(function() {
    //posts route
    this.resource('posts');
  });

  App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
      return this.store.find('post');
    }
  });
  App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    //data Model
    //setting book and author attr as string
    book: DS.attr('string'),
    author: DS.attr('string')
  });

  //attach fixtures(sample data) to the model's class
  App.Post.FIXTURES = [{
    id: 1,
    book: 'Java',
    author: 'Balaguruswamy'},{
    id: 2,
    book: 'C++',
    author: 'Herbert Schildt'},{
    id: 3,
    book: 'jQuery',
    author: 'Ryan Benedetti'
  }];
</script>
```

Comment: What ember version do you use? Seems to be a very old one. Have you considered to use `ember-cli` and a current ember version?

Comment: i am using ember1.1 and i want to execute it normally not by using ember-cli.

Comment: I can just strongly recommend to use at least ember `1.13`, or better a `2.x` version. Also especially when you are learning the framework you really should start with `ember-cli`, because all help you will find is for ember-cli. This is the *normal* way to use ember. If you don't see anything, also not `Books Name and Author:` your probably not in the `posts` route.

Comment: i have upgraded the CDN's to ember 2.6.1 still i am not getting any output in the browser.Is it not possible to execute it without using ember-cli?.

Comment: it is possible to use ember without ember-cli, still I *strongly recommend* not to do so. Also the `FixtureAdapter` has been removed from ember. And make sure you are in the `posts` route, your `index` route is empty. Any reasons why you don't want to use `ember-cli`?

Comment: yes I am in the post route and i have changed the adapter to REST adapter still i am not getting output.

Comment: Do you see the `Books Name and Author: ` or not? Is your backend responding? Any errors in the console? Gets `model` hook executed? Does the promise resolve?

Comment: k suggest me any tutorial or book that will help me to  implement same in ember-cli.

Comment: I suggest you the [official guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/) and `ember-cli`. If you don't have a backend yet checkout [mirage](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com). I *really* recommend you `ember-cli`. I hope I could help you.

Comment: thank you i will try it in ember-cli if any doubts i will contact you.